# Do I need to use the ampersand in PHP 5.5.X and above anymore?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, ampersand

I'm getting mixed signals all over the place.

Do I use the ampersand to pass variables by reference or not?

The following link seems to tell me that it is deprecated and no longer necessary:
http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/html/tutorials/tutorials.changes.references.html

But threads like these make me wonder:
[Call-time pass-by-reference deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010036/call-time-pass-by-reference-deprecated)
[PHP and ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682654/php-and-ampersand)

Let me phrase my question as an example.

If I make a function, using PHP 5.5.5:

```
function recurring_mailer_form($form, $form_state) 
{

}
```

Is it the same as:

```
function recurring_mailer_form($form, &$form_state) 
{

}
```

?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: "And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error."

Comment: @RUJordan "call-time pass-by-reference" is not the only kind of pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason different articles seem to be saying different things is that they are talking about different kinds of pass-by-reference.

The main thing that determines if a parameter should be passed by reference is the function signature itself, and the fundamentals of this have not changed since PHP 4. Consider this example:

```
function foo( $by_value, &$by_reference ) { /* ... */ }

$a = 1; $b = 2;
foo( $a, $b );
```

Here, the outer variable `$a` is being passed to the function by value, as though it is being assigned as `$by_value = $a;` - changes to `$by_value` cannot affect `$a`. The variable `$b` however is being passed *by reference*; just like an assignment of the form `$by_reference =& $b;` this means that there is one variable referenced by two names, and any assignment to one will act as an assignment to both.

If you pass an "ordinary" value (a string, number, or array) by value, its value is just copied to the new variable. **As of PHP 5**: If you pass an object by value, however, something slightly different happens - the "value" copied is just a pointer to the same object. This means that if `$a` were an object, you could call `$by_value->some_property = 42;` and `$a->some_property` would also be `42`. However, if you assigned some new value to `$by_value`, it would still not affect `$a`.

**Until PHP 5.4**, there was an *extra* way to pass a parameter by reference, which was to "force" the reference behaviour *at call-time*. This meant that you could write `foo(&$a, &$b);` and "capture" changes made to `$by_value` inside the `foo()` function. Relying on this was generally a bad idea, and so it was removed. (It landed in 5.4 because it was intended for removal in PHP 6, but that project was put on indefinite hold, with the smaller changes landing in 5.3 and 5.4).

Finally, functions can *return* a variable by reference (as [discussed in the manual here](http://php.net/references.return)). This is a little fiddly, as it actually requires you to put `&` in *two* places: at the beginning of the function declaration, to say that `return` should mean "return this variable reference" not "return this value"; and in the code calling it, to assign a variable to that reference, rather than just copying its value. Here's a silly example which combines a reference parameter with a reference return (the two do not have to go together, it's just an example):

```
function &bar(&$some_param) { return $some_param; }
$a = 1;
$b =& bar($a);
// $b and $a now point at the same variable, not just the same value
// it was passed into and out of a function, and assigned to a new variable, 
// but all those operations were by reference
```

Note that many people mistakenly believe that passing a variable by reference will give them a performance benefit, and this was often their only reason for using call-time pass-by-reference. This is in fact usually wrong, as the Zend Engine which powers PHP uses a technique called "copy on write" to leave multiple variables which happen to have the same value pointing at the same piece of memory, even if they are not bound up as references. In fact, reference assignment generally *defeats* this optimisation, due to the way the engine tracks which variables are in the copy-on-write state.

Comment: The last paragraph about performance is important, and what I came here looking for. Can you site some references for these conclusions?

Comment: @T.BrianJones If I think of where to find some good articles, I'll add them. If you want to have a search around, try searching for "zval" and "copy on write".

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.

- Objects are always automatically passed as references (**info!** see below for additional important information!)
- Declaring paramters as references must happen at the function definition:

  ```
  function test(&$var) {}
  ```

  **Not** at the time of calling it:

  ```
  // wrong
  $var = '123';
  test(&$var);
  ```

---

If you pass an object as usual, you can alter the object's state (properties).

Assume that `$obj` is an instance of the class `TestClass` which contains a member variable called `hello` ([click here for a full sample at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4mzU3P)):

```
function modify($obj) { $obj->hello = 'world (modified)!'; }

$obj->hello = 'world';
modify($obj);
var_dump($obj->hello);  // outputs "world (modified!)"
```

This should be self-explanatory. Now, using the same code but assigning another value to `$obj` instead modifying the object's state results in no modification ([→ Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/KopB7N)):

```
function modify($obj) { $obj = 42; }
// ...
var_dump($obj->hello);  // outputs "world"
```

Only accepting the parameter explicitly as a reference gives us the ability to completely change the variable's contents ([→ Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/XbFu7W)):

```
function modify(&$obj) { $obj = 42; }
// ...
var_dump($obj);         // outputs "42"
```

Comment: "Objects are always automatically passed as references" - this isn't quite correct (even though the manual occasionally says it is). If you pass a variable by reference, you can assign to that variable itself; if you pass by value, you cannot. Passing an object by value, however, does allow you to manipulate *the object*, using the `->` operator, etc

Comment: Good concise example :) People so often miss the difference between modifying the object and modifying the variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, those are not the same. PHP 5.4+ just detects on call whether reference is needed when the function is called by checking the declaration.

So no, not deprecated since you need the reference operator in the function declaration if that is your intended usage.

Comment: *Any* version of PHP detects on call whether a reference is needed according to the declaration. The difference is that prior to PHP 5.4 you could *force* a variable to be passed by reference *despite* the function declaration.