# delete Removes key from 2 objects

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects: one of them contains the player list and the other one contains players in loading screen.

When i remove a player from playersNotReady object, it also removes the player from the player list and i don't want that.

```js
var players = {
  1: "Player1",
  2: "Player2"
};
var playersNotReady = players;
delete playersNotReady[1];
console.log(players); // {2: "Player2"}
console.log(playersNotReady); // {2: "Player2"}
```

Why is this happening and how can i remove player from playersNotReady object without removing them from the actual player list?

Comment: You have to clone the object for playersNotReady because players and playersNotReady share the same object.

Comment: *"Why is this happening?"* -- the statement `var playersNotReady = players;` does not duplicate the value of `players`. It just adds a new reference to it. The object you create in the first lines of code can now be accessed through two variables: `players` and `playersNotReady`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a new variable. You are just pointing by reference. You can use `Object.assign` to clone/create new object.

```js
var players = {
  1: "Player1",
  2: "Player2"
};
var playersNotReady = Object.assign({}, players);
delete playersNotReady[1];
console.log(players); 
console.log(playersNotReady);
```

Doc: [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

---

One option also, is to use `Destructuring Assignment`, Like:

```js
var players = {
  1: "Player1",
  2: "Player2"
};
var {1: p1,...playersNotReady} = players; //This will create a new object and remove the 1
console.log(players);
console.log(playersNotReady);
```

Doc: [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var playersNotReady = players;` you are not creating a new object, but simply a new reference to the `players` object, this is because objects are [passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290747/pass-by-reference-javascript-objects) in javascript.

To create a new object, you can use the ES6 spread operator: `var playersNotReady = {...players};`

Answer (score 0):

while you assign `var playersNotReady = players;` it actually create a reference for players. not a new object. You can copy object by `Object.assign`.

```js
var players = {
  1: "Player1",
  2: "Player2"
};
var playersNotReady = Object.assign({}, players);
delete playersNotReady[1];
console.log(players); // {2: "Player2"}
console.log(playersNotReady); // {2: "Player2"}
```