# Set state of nested Array object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I setstate of value object inside datasets.I tried to set the state by below approach but got the error.

```
this.setState({ datasets: { ...this.state.datasets, value: labels} });
```

//code for state

```
this.state = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March',
                'April', 'May'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Rainfall',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    value: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56],
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: What error? Also, you should use functional update for `setState`.

Comment: I got the error value.datasets.map is not a function

Comment: This seems a separate problem. Though it could be related to setting the state wrong but maybe it is not? Please provide more code by updating your question.

Comment: After the second answer, I saw that your `datasets` is an array and you want to update it with incoming `labels` right? So, `labels` should replace the first `datasets`' `value`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state, datasets is an array. However, in the setstate call you are destructuring it as an object. You should do this to get it to work:

```
this.setState({ datasets: [ {...this.state.datasets[0], value: labels }] });
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that it is an array. Ok, for one item this should work, also I suggest using functional `setState` here.

Comment: Agreed. I just pointed out the mistake OP was making in his original code, but I hope he takes note of it and uses the functional setState in his actual code.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I'm totally clear on what you are trying to do, but I think the issue is that state.datasets is an array of objects, and you aren't addressing a particular element in the array. You may want to try something along these lines:

```
this.setState( state => { 
    let newData = state.datasets[0]
    newData.value = labels
    return newData
}
```

Comment: Not a good way for updating state. Do not assign any state property to variable and change it. It mutates the state.

Comment: See [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: But I'm not mutating state directly. I am using the functional this.setState. How is that a problem?

Comment: They are different things I guess. You are using the functional update but still, mutating the current state you have there. PS: I'm not the one downvoted you :)

Comment: @justin it's a common mistake in React that comes from a misunderstanding of assignment/copying. When you assign `newData`, [it copies a reference to the same state object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290849/1218980), which you then mutate. Why it's a mistake in React is explained really well in the other link I shared.

Comment: Did a bunch of reading up and feel much better informed on safely updating state. Learning good stuff - thanks for all the info and explanation!