# How to rerender the tree in antd after adding a node to an existing node?

Tags: reactjs, tree, antd

I am using [Antd Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/) to render the tree view of the data, at the beginning the data of the tree is a flat array of objects with each object having a key `parentId` indicating the parent of that node.

I am then using a function to convert this flat array into hierarchical structure to pass it to the `Tree` component of the `antd` library

[Please refer this Codesandbox link to see the project code](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sea-mrrjs?file=/src/components/TreeView.js)
the flat array is in the [data.json](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sea-mrrjs?file=/src/data.json) file in the `src` folder

I have done this because pasting the entire code of the project would look clumsy. There is a textbox to enter the new nodes name after selecting an existing node in the tree as the parent of the new node, there are no errors and in the `render` method in the console the updated state is also getting logged correctly but the tree is not getting rendered reflecting the updated data, I am using `shouldComponentUpdate` method thinking it would update the `DOM` if anyone could resolve the problem then it will be a great help
THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is in the **handleAddNode** function you update the **flatTree** from the component's state, but based on the code below:

```
<Tree
  treeData={this.state.hirarchicalTree}
  onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}
/>
```

, the **treeData** prop is given from **hirarchicalTree**.

The **flatTree** is up to date, but the **hirarchicalTree** no, so you need to update it from the flat tree.

The **shouldComponentUpdate** function doesn't help you, so you can remove it.

You have two options to update the **hirarchicalTree:

1. Using a [setState callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
2. Adding **componentDidUpdate**, and do an update if **flatTree** is different than before

Basically update the **hirarchicalTree** from the **flatTree** in the way you first set it in **componentDidMount**

After this you'll have another problem at this block:

```
[...flat].forEach(function(item) {
  all[item.id] = item;
});
```

As **item** is an Object, when you assign it, **all[item.id]** will point to the same reference as item from the **flat** variable.

So when you'll add children, they will be added also on the items from the **flatTree**, rendering duplicates in the page. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290849/13846805) answer.

You can fix it by doing this:

```
[...flat].forEach(function(item) {
  all[item.id] = { ...item };
});
```

This will make a shallow copy, but as we don't have nested fields in item, it's fine.

Working codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-cherry-th13o?file=/src/components/TreeView.js)