# Why template is not changed? - Angular

Tags: angular

Template is:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
     <div (click)=""edit(row)></div>
  </tr>
```

Component is:

```
 public edit(row: PostAddress): void {
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((postaddress) => {
            if (postaddress) {
                row = postaddress;
                 this._change.markForCheck();
            } 
 }
```

I see that variable was chnaged on a new value:  `row = postaddress;` but template does not render.

I use     `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Also I have tried this:

```
 row = postaddress;
 this._change.markForCheck();
 this._change.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `changeDetection`, when assigning `row = postaddress;` the reference to the original row is lost, thus is not pointing to the one in the array any more, (`row` doesn't contain the `row` itself, rather a reference to it, when assigning to it a new object, it would hold a reference to the new object.)

```js
public edit(row: PostAddress): void {
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((postaddress) => {
    if (postaddress)
    {
      rows.splice(rows.indexOf(row), 1, postaddress)
    }
  }
```

Or optionally using `index` provided by `ngFor`:

```js
public edit(row: PostAddress, index : number): void {
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((postaddress) => {
   if (postaddress)
   {
    rows[index] = postaddress
   }
}
```

Comment: Why `row` is lost? How to reassign value then?

Comment: could you explain why link is lost?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reassigning a element in the array, you could try to send the index and modify the element in the parent array. Try the following

Template

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
  <div (click)="edit(index)></div>
</tr>
```

Controller

```js
public edit(index): void {
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((postaddress) => {
    if (postaddress) {
      this.rows[i] = postaddress;     // <-- change item in the array
      this._change.markForCheck();
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: could you explain why link is lost?

Comment: Object assignments are finicky in Javascript. They are pseudo pass-by-reference. So when you assign another object to the variable, it ceases the reference. You could refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/6513921) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290849/6513921) for more info.