# Random method returns same object

Tags: javascript, object, variables, random

I'm learning javascript and made an exercise to practise using objects. I've got an `generateRandomPerson()` function to take person-object, give it random properties then return the object. When I call the method `generateRandomPerson().getInfo()` twice it prints two different objects. But when I create two different variables and assign them to `generateRandomPerson()` the variables contains identical objects. I don't understand why this is happening?

Object

```
person = {
  details :{
    name : null,
    surName : null,
    age : null,
    accBalance : null
  },
  personalCar : null,
  setName(givenName){
    this.details.name = givenName;
  },
  setSurName(givenName){
    this.details.surName = givenName;
  },
  setAge(givenAge){
    this.details.age = givenAge;
  },
  setAccBalance(givenBalance){
    this.details.accBalance = givenBalance;
  },
  setPersonalCar(givenCar){
    this.personalCar = givenCar;
  },
  getInfo(){
    for(let detail in this.details){
      console.log(`${detail}: ${this.details[detail]}`);
    }
  },
  getHTML(){
    let mainContainer = document.createElement('div');
    for(let detail in this.details){
      let info = document.createElement('p');
      info.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${detail}: ${this.details[detail]}`));
      mainContainer.appendChild(info);
    }
    return mainContainer;
  }
}
```

`generateRandomPerson()`

```
generateRandomPerson = () =>{
  let genPer = person;
  genPer.setName(names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]);
  genPer.setSurName(surNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * surNames.length)]);
  genPer.setAge(Math.floor(Math.random() * 62) + 18);
  genPer.setAccBalance(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000)+1000);
  genPer.setPersonalCar(generateRandomCar());
  return genPer;
}
```

Why does the variables contain the same object but calling `generateRandomPerson().getInfo();` twice generate two different objects?

```
let man0 = generateRandomPerson();
let man1 = generateRandomPerson();

man0.getInfo(); //Loggs a person
man1.getInfo(); //Loggs the same person

generateRandomPerson().getInfo(); //Loggs a person
generateRandomPerson().getInfo(); //Loggs a new person
```

Comment: `let genPer = person;` - This does not _"create two different"_ persons. There will be two `genPer` variables but they will both point to the same spot in the memory where the `person` object is located

Comment: [Pass-by-reference JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290747/pass-by-reference-javascript-objects), [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I see. You might see that I'm trying to use person as a template for creating objects. It seems to me that I dont really know what I'm doing, but how do you think I should go about creating several person objects containing different properties?

Comment: There are three links in my comment. Two for the _"why"_ and one for the _"how"_.