# Why old objects are updated when updating assigned new object with old one

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Kinda messy, but take a look at this and you will understand

```js
var oldObject = { hello: "world" },
    newObject = { who: "cares" };

newObject["newStuff"] = oldObject;

console.log(oldObject)
console.log(newObject)

newObject["newStuff"]["hello"] = null;

console.log(oldObject)
console.log(newObject)
```

I am not having issues but i really want to know why !!!!

After comments i recieved this example:
x.member = "bar"; // Updated original object
x = { member: "bar" }; // Didnt updated it

BUT let's say i have a really big big big object with 10 or 15 arguments,
how can i use the second idea without putting a mess inside my code? :)

Comment: because it is a reference, not a copy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language might help?

Comment: Please do consider using https://justjavascript.com/

Comment: @TusharShahi This is neither a deep copy nor a shallow copy. It's not a copy at all.

Comment: FYI `newObject["newStuff"]` is more commonly written `newObject.newStuff` (unless the key includes whitespace).

Comment: TLDR: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290849/1046690