# need help in javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, json

From the following snippet, I have to iterate through all receipts, get the receipt number, and add that object to the JSON. But I am getting the same receipt in two JSON. Where am I missing? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
const shopList = [];
const shop = {
"shopNumber": "2242461",
"shopDate": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00",
"shopAmount": "100",
"shopBank": "HDFC",
"shopDetails": {
    "shopNumber": "1242461",
    "shopDate": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00",
    "shopBank": "HDFC",
    "shopAmount": "100"
},
"receiptDetails": [{
        "userNumber": "115729",
        "receiptNumber": "temp1"
    },
    {
        "userNumber": "115726",
        "receiptNumber": "temp2"
    }
]

};
 shop.receiptDetails.forEach((receipt) => {
var temp = shop.shopDetails;
temp.receiptNumber = receipt.receiptNumber;
shopList.push({
    shopNumber: shop.shopNumber,
    userNumber: Number(receipt.userNumber),
    receiptNumber: receipt.receiptNumber,
    shopDetails: temp,
    isSync: 0
});
});
shopList.forEach((receipt) => {
console.log(receipt);
});
```

I am getting output as

```
{
shopNumber: '2242461',
userNumber: 115729,
receiptNumber: 'temp1',
shopDetails: {
    shopNumber: '1242461',
    shopDate: '2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00',
    shopBank: 'HDFC',
    shopAmount: '100',
    receiptNumber: 'temp2' ----**this should be temp1**
},
isSync: 0
} {
shopNumber: '2242461',
userNumber: 115726,
receiptNumber: 'temp2',
shopDetails: {
    shopNumber: '1242461',
    shopDate: '2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00',
    shopBank: 'HDFC',
    shopAmount: '100',
    receiptNumber: 'temp2'    
},
isSync: 0
}
```

Comment: Please note that you have no JSON in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `temp` is a reference to `shop.shopDetails`. Objects in JavaScript are passed by reference, when you assign the `temp.receiptNumber`, it equals to `shop.shopDetails.receiptNumber` - Therefore, the `temp` value that you get in the **next iterations** is carried over from the **last iteration**

Read more about how javascript objects variable works in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290849/1627271), I think it explains it very well.

As for your approach, one of many ways you could solve it is to clone the object of `shop.shopDetails` in each iteration, therefore you'll get a new object instead.

E.g.

```js
const shopList = [];
const shop = {
    "shopNumber": "2242461",
    "shopDate": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00",
    "shopAmount": "100",
    "shopBank": "HDFC",
    "shopDetails": {
        "shopNumber": "1242461",
        "shopDate": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00",
        "shopBank": "HDFC",
        "shopAmount": "100"
    },
    "receiptDetails": [{
        "userNumber": "115729",
        "receiptNumber": "temp1"
    },
    {
        "userNumber": "115726",
        "receiptNumber": "temp2"
    }]
};

shop.receiptDetails.forEach((receipt) => {
    var temp = {...shop.shopDetails}; // This is to clone an object, there are other ways than this.
    temp.receiptNumber = receipt.receiptNumber;
    shopList.push({
        shopNumber: shop.shopNumber,
        userNumber: Number(receipt.userNumber),
        receiptNumber: receipt.receiptNumber,
        shopDetails: temp,
        isSync: 0
    });
});

shopList.forEach((receipt) => {
    console.log(receipt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are causing the duplicate receipt number since you are essentially adding the same JSON object to the `shopList`. Only the last update remains.

```js
var temp = shop.shopDetails;
temp.receiptNumber = receipt.receiptNumber;
```

I recommend you to clone `shopDetails` to which you add `receiptNumber`.

```js
var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shop.shopDetails));
```

Here is your modified code:

```js
const shopList = [];
const shop = {
  "shopNumber": "2242461",
  "shopDate": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00",
  "shopAmount": "100",
  "shopBank": "HDFC",
  "shopDetails": {
    "shopNumber": "1242461",
    "shopDate": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000-05:00",
    "shopBank": "HDFC",
    "shopAmount": "100"
  },
  "receiptDetails": [{
    "userNumber": "115729",
    "receiptNumber": "temp1"
  },
  {
    "userNumber": "115726",
    "receiptNumber": "temp2"
  }
  ]

};
shop.receiptDetails.forEach((receipt) => {
  var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shop.shopDetails));
  temp.receiptNumber = receipt.receiptNumber;
  shopList.push({
    shopNumber: shop.shopNumber,
    userNumber: Number(receipt.userNumber),
    receiptNumber: receipt.receiptNumber,
    shopDetails: temp,
    isSync: 0
  });
});
shopList.forEach((receipt) => {
  console.log(receipt);
});
```